# Making Azure Virtual Machine VPN-Ready

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

My company is integrating with this company to enable us both consume services built on each other's platform to provide joint services extended to external users.

They recently sent me a file containing their VPN configuration with spaces provided to enter ours as well. Now I am not so savvy about VPNs plus our server is hosted in an Azure VM (windows server 2012 R2). I don't know if our hosting arrangement is VPN-ready by default. How am I supposed to go about this?
Any helpful articles or guidance is a welcome boon at this time.

PS.
My knowledge on networking is next to nothing. Just know the basest of things there.

Comment: Tutorial recommendation questions are off-topic for StackOverflow. Further: This isn't a programming question (again, off topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two options to create the VPN to your cloud infrastructure:

1) By external services like OpenVPN - in that case, your involvement into what should be done will be to open some endpoints. [Tutorials](http://www.codepool.biz/virtual-machine-openvpn-microsoft-azure.html) are available.

2) By internal service called Virtual Network. In that case, you should first place your VM to the Virtual Network, and then use [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-vnet-arm-pportal/). As the networking is a big topic, i would propose you to read the official [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-site-to-site-create/) instead of putting that information here.

So, basically, to get your VM ready for the VPN, you should:

1) Create Virtual Network

2) Place the VM into that VN

3) Configure both cloud and local gateways

4) Install the VPN client.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Belotserkovskiy

Comment: If you will have any questions, feel free to create a new one and i will be happy to try to help. Thanks!

Comment: It turns out that you cannot move your existing VM to your VNet without deleting it and losing your virtual IP (even though you preserve the disk). 
That is really an issue for me as that VIP is already in circulation amongst our very many clients.
Is there another way around this that you know and can share?